# How to create a new table with a column in currency format in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm losing my mind y'all, please don't roast me, so I have to make a new table in SQL with the columns "Name" and "totalpername". First, from the table "money" I turned the varchar into integer, summed the money up, and I used the following syntax to create a new table and make the summed up money into currency format.

```
INSERT INTO TotalTable AS
SELECT Name, FORMAT(SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(Money, '$', ''), ',', '')), 'C', 'en-US') totalpername
from money
GROUP BY Name;
```

and the error says: Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect INTEGER value: 'C'

What to do? Tried creating a new table first and specifying the column "totalpername" with decimal(18,2) for 2 decimal places and 18 numbers before decimal
Thanks :)

Comment: You are missing a (correct) second parameter, see: [FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format)

Comment: You have a table called money with a column called money? and that column is a string? It would be useful if you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provided table definitions and sample data as text.

Comment: "with decimal(18,2) for 2 decimal places and 18 numbers before decimal"  No, that is with (18-2=) 16 numbers before decimal.  (Which is still huge, unless you are focused on `money` )

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to FORMAT the SUM before inserting it.
It would be better if your could keep the money in the table money in a correct decimal format.
NB I have added an underscore at the end of **money_** because it is a reserved word in some RDBMS.

> ```
> create table TotalTable(name varchar(10), totalpername decimal(18,2));
> create table money_(name varchar(10), money_ varchar(10));
> insert into money_ values('Bill','10.50$'),('Bill','$20');
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO TotalTable (Name, totalpername)
> SELECT 
> Name, 
> SUM(REPLACE(REPLACE(money_, '$', ''), ',', '')) totalpername
> from money_
> GROUP BY Name;
> ```

> ```
> select * from TotalTable;
> ```
>
> ```
> name | totalpername
> :--- | -----------:
> Bill |        30.50
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f92c7fd3e2cadf2ea9c1733939721cbf)*